# Why are they identically distributed? (An example of compound Poisson Process from Introduction to Probability models 11th edition)

Tags: stochastic-processes, poisson-process

Consider a single-server service in which customers arrive according to a Poisson process with rate $\lambda$. Successive service times are independent with common distribution.

There exists two periods in such a system, one is called idle periods when there are no customers and the other is busy periods when there are at least one customer in the system, so the length of a busy period is defined as the elapsed time from the arrival of the first customer to the departure of the last customer.

Let $B$ be the length of a busy period and let $N(S)$ be the number of arrivals during time S, where $S$ denotes the service time of the first customer. For $N(S) = 1$, which indicates another customer arrives the system while the first customer is being served, the length of the busy period can be expressed as follows
$$B = S+B_1$$
where $B_1$ is the additional time from S until the system becomes empty, so I assume $B_1$ is the service time for the second customer.

Then the book says because of the memoryless property of Poisson process, $B_1$ has the same distribution as $B$ and I wonder how this hold, since $P(B<x) = P(S+B_1<x)$ and for $B_1$, it's just $P(B_1<x)$

Comment: I guess what they may mean is the following: given that the f second customer arrives, $B_1 > B$ with probability $1$. Yet there’s no guarantee that the they will arrive. At the same time, $B_1$ is only defined on samples where the new customer arrives during the service time for the first one. You can’t actually say that $B_1 > B$ everywhere since the former is either not defined on samples where there’s just one isolated customer

Comment: I assume you mean $B>B_1$ with probability 1 when given the second customer arrives. And in such a situation how can $B$ and $B_1$ has the same distribution?

Comment: In the post I said "I assume $B_1$ is the service time of the second customer", which is probably wrong, since there can be other customers who arrive during the service time of the second customer and such a situation also satisfies $N(S) = 1$